# Given a set, find the total number of functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. The number of functions $f: A \rightarrow A$ such that $f(f(2))=2$ is?

My approach:-
I figured out $f(2)$ can be any number from set $A$ so that can be selected in $5$ ways. I supposed it to be $4$ then $f(4)$ must be $2$ as per question. Now, i got $5$ ways until now and $f(2)$ and $f(4)$ already fixed. I did this $3-4$ times and i get different answers. Im missing certain cases probably. Is there any better way to tackle this out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the right idea.  We can construct any such function by the following steps:

**Case 1:** $f(2) = 2$

If $f(2) = 2$, the remaining values of $f$ can be chosen at will, yielding $5^4$ such possibilities.

**Case 2:** $f(2) \neq 2$

We can construct any such function by the following process:

1. Decide what $f(2)$ is (4 possibilities)
2. Set $f(f(2)) = 2$ (no choice)
3. The remaining values of $f$ can be chosen at will ($5^3$) possibilities

Putting the two cases together, we have
$$
5^4 + 4\cdot 5^3 = 9 \cdot 5^3 = 1125
$$

Comment: @user354545 not 2 "images", but 2 elements that are both sent to $2$, which is possible.

Comment: Like, i made 3 ovals having numbers, started arranging. Did f(2)=2. 2 in oval a meets 2 in oval b. 2 in oval b meets 2 in oval c. Now if i arrange 1 in oval a to 2 in oval b, then 2 in oval b will be automatically meet 2 in oval c as per the first case. I dont get this :(

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with those ovals

Comment: Like an arrow diagram

Comment: @Omnomnomnom can we continue discussion in private chat?

Comment: @user354545 The point is this: if $f(2) = 2$, then *no matter what else happens* with the function, $f(f(2)) = 2$.  Similarly, if $f(2) \neq 2$ and $f(f(2)) = 2$, then *no matter what else happens*, we have $f(f(2)) = 2$.  Does that much make sense?

Comment: Yes, i get u in that. Im just asking if in the first case, any other element arranges itself to 2, what does this actually mean?

Comment: For example: we could have
$$
f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = f(4) = f(5) = 2
$$
This would be a function with $f(f(x)) = 2$ for any $x$. What's the problem here?  What "actual meaning" are you looking for?